# Command line options for retrieving all of the files being accessed by a particular program

Tags: windows, command-line, process-monitor

I'm trying to access the files being used by a given program in Windows, via a command line prompt in a .bat script.  I've found the program Process Monitor, but can't find a CLI way to do this.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) (also from Sysinternals), not Process Monitor.
Handle application must run elevated (administrator)

```
handle -p myproc
```

Will return all handles for processes begin with the 'myproc'.

```
handle -pid 1234
```

Will return all handles for process with pid 1234.

You could also use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) if you want GUI.